# Android linearlayout with floating button

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to make floating button in my main xml that include linearlayout for my list of items (I know that I can use list view but foe my mission I need to use the linearlayout method). All my trying are fail all the time because the button fits inside of the text liens that used in the linearlayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/infofo"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="test" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I would be happy if someone can help me to achieve this. Thanks.

EDIT -

This is the problem, the solution need to be only one button on the bottom of the screen as floating action button.
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6Uta.png)

Comment: why are u trying to make a floating action button? Android has default widget for That   `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I try to add this into this android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton to the xml but it all the time duplicate it into the textview rows. ?maybe do you know way ?

Comment: are u adding it in your listview row layout ?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 yes

Comment: Add `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` in your activity's  layout where the `ListView` is hosted..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 but there is no ListView, it is only the LinearLayout with the textview

Comment: okay ...add it in your activity's layout under `LinearLayout`

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 But I can make multiplay root tags, can you explain exactly where the Action Button need to be ?

Comment: i have added an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put in your vertical LinearLayout will be drawn below the other elements. You should add your Floating button beside the LinearLayout inside another Layout capable of handling this (eg. FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, CoordinatorLayout etc)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/infofo"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="test" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But in your example I get into the same problem that the button inside the text in the linearLayout.

Comment: I am sorry it is not clear what you want to do.
Try with a screenshot maybe?

Comment: is this whole layout your floating button(text and button) that you want to fit in another list of text? If yes then you have to fix it where you are adding this layout(floating button), not in this layout

Comment: I edit the question and add screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Editing my answer to get your button to the bottom

Comment: the mission is only one floating action button (use as setting it the future) and the LinearLayout with the text is separate part (action as list of items).

Comment: try it now, with the changes in the button

Comment: But still the Button and the text are connected to the same line as in the screenshot I took. Why :( ?

Comment: if you add more TextViews in the LinearLayout, does the button go lower?

Comment: yes the button go lower, with any new text it enter down.

Comment: I copied an error from your code on the TextView. Sorry.
Try again now, I changed the layout_width and layout_height attributes.

Also if the button goes lower it means that your whole layout (RelativeLayout) is inside a container that has layout_height="wrap_content"
You have to change this parent container to layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: where do you use this layout?
You have to make sure that all Parents of this layout have layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: This layout has no any parents.

Comment: is it loaded in an activity directly?

Comment: It is working for me.
Empty project, just changed the activity_main.xml 
The only change is I am using FloatingActionButton instead of plain Button
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxVlnNdbnv9iS1pKa0tWRGRpQUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes it is show me the same but the result are as in my answer.

Comment: Please check again your parents' layout_height. It has to be match_parent. Additionaly If you are containing this layout on some other layout then it also has to be match_parent.

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

There is no other way it would not show as expected